# meld takes ages to open and fails with org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor:: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, sshfs, meld

`git mergetool` opening `meld` takes ages to open and finally fails with:

```
invoking IsSupported() failed for remote volume monitor with dbus name org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor:: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
```

It was working fine not long ago and no system updates were installed. No other tools seem to have this problem.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The reason was a failed `sshfs` attempt elsewhere on the system and seemingly completely unrelated to the git repository. The `sshfs` command had hung while connecting. Even after killing it, accessing the mount point produced the error `Transport endpoint is not connected`.

The solution was to ctrl-c the `sshfs` command and unbind the failed mount point with `fusermount -u /path/to/mount`.